# Back Button Refuses to Hide

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, back

For some odd reason I cannot hide the back button from the navigation bar.

I've tried everything below, but nothing works.

Any other suggestions?

**The "Back" button appears, but nothing happens when pressed.

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=nil;
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem=nil;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=nil;
    self.navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton=YES;
```

Comment: Update your question with more details. Provide more details about your setup. What is your view controller/navigation controller setup? For which view controller do you want to hide the back button? And why?

Comment: would making an `IBOutlet` to the BackButton, then setting `BackButton.hidden = true` work? or try to disable the BackButton and set the alpha to 0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to hide back button:

```
[self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```